# Is it a good practice not to use returned value of a method?

Tags: c#

Here's my method:

```
   public static bool ValidateAddressCount(ref long o_addressCount)
    {
  // o_addressCount is modified here
  //return true or false
   }
```

I've reached some case when i don't care what the method returns, i just need the o_adressCount
Is it a good practice to use this method in the following way:

```
  long addressCount =  0;
  ValidateAddressCount(ref addressCount); //without assigning the returned value to any variable
  //use address count
```

Also, can anyone explain why this works in .net?

Thank you

Comment: I think it's good practice to use `out` modifier instead of `ref` for arguments that are actually "secondary" return values, because `out`, unlike `ref`, doesn't require the argument to be initialized before passing it.

Comment: (I personally reserve `out` or `ref` for *very* special situations.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why it works is easy:

```
long addressCount =  0;
ValidateAddressCount(ref addressCount);
```

is of the same form as

```
long addressCount =  0;
true;
```

Any `<expression> ;` is a valid statement.

There is a valid question here though:

- Why is there no warning for this syntax which is quite likely a mistake?

Because in general it is not a good practice to ignore a return value.

Comment: Eric Lippert usually says: because none it implemented :)

Comment: I don't think this one falls into that category (of 'features').

Comment: Some languages do not allow an expression (never mind a function call "that returns a value") to appear as a top-level statement.

Answer (score 4):

Its upto the developer. No hard rules in it.

Like in `bool int.TryParse(string s, out int a){}`

When we pass a value to be converted into `int` value it returns a `bool` value and uses the out variable to send converted value.

Sometimes we need to check whether it has been converted or not. That's where we use return value.

```
string str = "1";
int a = 0;

if(int.TryParse(str, out a))
    MessageBox.Show("Converted");
else
    MessageBox.Show("Not Converted");
```

Tryparse can be used simply as

```
bool b = int.TryParse(str, out a);
```

Let's say bool value returned is of no use to me. Then why waste memory by creating a variable(`b`), assigning it a value and not using it. So i will write it as

```
int.TryParse(str, out a);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works because you declared a method with `return-value`, which means that you **may** want care about that `return-value`, but it's not mandatory option.

Answer (score 1):

Use ref/out when calling method want the changes of called method in passed parameter.

Otherwise, it's not a good choice to use ref/out.

You should use dynamic object/tuple if want to return more than one value from called method.

Comment: I would not recommend the use of `dynamic` here. Tuples are nice, but are .NET 4 BCL feature and do not have a notion of "named" properties as records or new types.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use the result of the method, you can just call it for its side effect. However, it's usually a good idea to avoid using `ref`, if you can. In your case, you can just return `long?`.

Answer (score 0):

No you dont need to assign the return value.. but in my opinion, method as `validateSomething(object)` should have a return value if the object is valid or not and it shoud be important to check for the return value.

If the method does something with the object, it shouldnt be called just `validateSomething(object)`, but `validateAndChangeSomething(object)`... now it is confusing what it is doing and what is the primary output of the validation: the return value or the modified object..

Answer (score 0):

Whilst what you have written works, I don't think it's particularly obvious what your method is doing.

Things have moved on a bit since I first started coding but I believe that nowdays it good practice to make your code readable to humans first and then comment the hell out of it if you really have to do something unexpected.

With that in mind, I'd tweak your code to provide a property to obtain the count and modify the method so that you wouldn't need a parameter.

I know this doesn't answer the "use a method and ignore the return type" part of your question but I think that's subjective on  what your are doing at the time.